# Twisted Trial: How to test a MultiService with a client in it -- Reactor was unclean

Tags: python, unit-testing, twisted, trial

I've inherited a Twisted MultiService that I'm trying to add tests to, but whatever I do, I end up with a DirtyReactorAggregateError. The service connects to a server with a `twisted.application.internet.TCPClient`. I think the error is because the TCPClient is not disconnecting, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to disconnect it. What is the proper way to test a Twisted Service with a client in it?

Here's the test case:

```
from labrad.node import *
from twisted.trial import unittest
import os
from socket import gethostname

class NodeTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        import labrad
        name = os.environ.get('LABRADNODE', gethostname()) + '_test'
        self.node = Node(name,
            labrad.constants.MANAGER_HOST,
            labrad.constants.MANAGER_PORT)
        self.node.startService()
        #self.addCleanup(self.node.stopService)

    def test_nothing(self):
        self.assertEqual(3, 3)

    def tearDown(self):
        return self.node.stopService()
```

Here's the Node service itself:

```
class Node(MultiService):
    """Parent Service that keeps the node running.

    If the manager is stopped or we lose the network connection,
    this service attempts to restart it so that we will come
    back online when the manager is back up.
    """
    reconnectDelay = 10

    def __init__(self, name, host, port):
        MultiService.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

    def startService(self):
        MultiService.startService(self)
        self.startConnection()

    def startConnection(self):
        """Attempt to start the node and connect to LabRAD."""
        print 'Connecting to %s:%d...' % (self.host, self.port)
        self.node = NodeServer(self.name, self.host, self.port)
        self.node.onStartup().addErrback(self._error)
        self.node.onShutdown().addCallbacks(self._disconnected, self._error)
        self.cxn = TCPClient(self.host, self.port, self.node)
        self.addService(self.cxn)

    def stopService(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'cxn'):
            d = defer.maybeDeferred(self.cxn.stopService)
            self.removeService(self.cxn)
            del self.cxn
            return defer.gatherResults([MultiService.stopService(self), d])
        else:
            return MultiService.stopService(self)

    def _disconnected(self, data):
        print 'Node disconnected from manager.'
        return self._reconnect()

    def _error(self, failure):
        r = failure.trap(UserError)
        if r == UserError:
            print "UserError found!"
            return None
        print failure.getErrorMessage()
        return self._reconnect()

    def _reconnect(self):
        """Clean up from the last run and reconnect."""
        ## hack: manually clearing the dispatcher...
        dispatcher.connections.clear()
        dispatcher.senders.clear()
        dispatcher._boundMethods.clear()
        ## end hack
        if hasattr(self, 'cxn'):
            self.removeService(self.cxn)
            del self.cxn
        reactor.callLater(self.reconnectDelay, self.startConnection)
        print 'Will try to reconnect in %d seconds...' % self.reconnectDelay
```

Answer (score 2):

You should refactor your service so that it can use something like `MemoryReactor` from `twisted.test.proto_helpers` (the one public module in the `twisted.test` package, although hopefully it will move out of `twisted.test` eventually).

The way that you use `MemoryReactor` is to pass it into your code as the reactor to use.  If you then want to see what happens when the connection succeeds, look at some of its public attributes - `tcpClients` for `connectTCP`, `tcpServers` for `listenTCP`, etc.  Your tests can then pull out the Factory instances which were passed to `connectTCP`/`listenTCP`, etc, and call `buildProtocol` on them and `makeConnection` on the result.  To get an `ITransport` implementation you can use [`twisted.test.proto_helpers.StringTransportWithDisconnection`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.4.0/api/twisted.test.proto_helpers.StringTransportWithDisconnection.html).  You might even look at the (private API! be careful! it'll break without warning! although it [really should be public](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/5354)) `twisted.test.iosim.IOPump` to relay traffic between clients and servers.

If you really actually need to do whole-system non-deterministic real-world testing, with all the complexity and random unrelated failures that implies, [here's an article on actually shutting down a client and server all the way](https://mumak.net/stuff/twisted-disconnect.html).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm very new to Twisted so I'm looking to avoid any major refactorings, but if that's what it takes I'll figure it out.

Comment: [continued...] I actually came across that article while googling and I couldn't figure out how to get the TCP client to shut down all the way; that is, I couldn't figure out what exactly I need to call and what deferred to wait on. I couldn't find good documentation for TCPService or Twisted Services in general. (I looked all over the trac/wiki but there didn't seem to be anything about services, for example.) Perhaps you could point me to some documentation?

Comment: Have you seen https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/application.html#services-provided-by-twisted ?

Comment: Can you expand on your advice about [`MemoryReactor`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.test.proto_helpers.MemoryReactor.html)? The documentation says, "This reactor doesn't actually do much that's useful yet. It accepts TCP connection setup attempts, but they will never succeed." This doesn't seem as if it would help the OP.

Comment: @GarethRees - good point; I added a lot of words.  hopefully the expanded answer is of some use to you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with trying to test a instance of an application. I ended up creating a Python base class that used setUp and tearDown methods to start/stop the application.

```
from twisted.application.app import startApplication
from twisted.application.service import IServiceCollection
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
from twisted.trial import unittest

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        startApplication(self.app, save=False)

    @inlineCallbacks
    def tearDown(self):
        sc = self.app.getComponent(IServiceCollection)
        yield sc.stopService()
```